# replicating a matrix in the 3rd dimension in scilab

Tags: scilab

I'd like to replicate an NxM matrix into an NxMx3 matrix, i.e. have 3 copies of the input matrix in the third dimension. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A is your NxM matrix, then the NxMx3 matrix is:

`B = hypermat([size(A), 3], kron(ones(3, 1), A(1:$)))`

or

```
B = hypermat([size(A), 3], ones(3, 1).*.A(1:$))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better and simpler answer (without using any operator):

```
B = A(:,:,[1 1 1])
```

Example (two copies are enough here):

```
-> a=[1 2;3 4]
 a  = 

   1.   2.
   3.   4.

--> a(:,:,[1 1])
 ans  =

(:,:,1)

   1.   2.
   3.   4.
(:,:,2)

   1.   2.
   3.   4.
```